# Google Translate in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

How do I enable google translation without prompting?

I read a lot of texts in foreign language and clicking each time is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: Browsing the Settings might help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is only due to running in incongnito mode. Normal Running Keeps everything normal and above options are shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to <kbd>Options</kbd> `->` <kbd>Always translate (Language) to English</kbd>. (note that you will have to do this once for each language, there is unfortunately no way to do this for all languages)

[image]

(click the image to view a larger image)

Comment: Exactly, I have common sense enough to check that but the first three options don't show up in my browser, Which Version is Yours? or Which OS?

Comment: @ήλιος, I'm seeing [it in Chromium 11](http://i.imgur.com/caKWB36.png), (though I had to first (re-)check the `Offer to translate…` option in Settings, which somehow got turned off). Also, unless you are missing the options in *every* language (you can easily check by visiting different language versions of Wikipedia), then you may have [turned translation off](http://www.shadegrowncode.com/2012/05/undo-google-chrome-never-translate-page.html) for that specific language.